# How do I make two items in the same table cell have different text alignments?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table containing a list of products. I want each row to only have one cell, with the name of a product left-aligned on it. But I also want to add an edit option(a hyperlink called 'Edit'), right-aligned on the same line, in the same table cell. Since `<td>` elements are left-aligned by default, I added a class attribute to Edit's `<a>` tags and used that to style it, but it's still left-aligned. Any idea how to solve this?

This is the CSS code for the edit option's class:

```
.editLink{
    text-align: right;  
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555555;
    font-size: smaller;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use float on the edit link.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
}

.editLink {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555555;
  font-size: smaller;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.editLink::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked, but I didn't understand the purpose of this snippet, could you please explain? ```.editLink::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}```

Comment: It's called a clearfix. It's a CSS hack to clear the floats and to ensure that the following items are positioned correctly.